# Would I use \catcode, tokens, or look outside of tex for a markdown-like parser solution?

Tags: beamer, macros, templates, catcodes

My use case: a LaTeX template for courseware designed in a beamer presentation style. The template I'm designing is company-specific and the specificity of the company's presentation guidelines limits the type of content users of the template will be including.

I am trying to create markdown-like shortcuts for beamer presentations, I am wondering if I should use \catcode altering, tokens, or just design an external parsing solution; I would like to isolate these shortcuts to environments that take specific content (courseware authors would be writing the content in plain text with syntax for bolding, coloring, italicization, itemization, numeration, but not much else). Is there a LaTeX solution that could make this happen? Would it be better not to meddle with such unorthodoxy?

PS. I don't want suggestions of Pandoc or equivalent, I just want to know if this is a good or bad idea and why!

Comment: Parsing in TeX is a bad idea because it's very hard to recover from errors and give meaningful feedback to users. Better use an external program for that task.

Comment: Yeah I'll take that advice!

Comment: @StephanLehmke Do you want to make that an asnwer?